# Multiple android device connection throught wifi local network

Tags: android, wifi, ktor-client

I want to use 2 android devices, 1 as a server and 2 as a client. And this process should be through the local network, so the 1st device will have to open a hotspot and the 2nd device will have to connect to it. I did the same process but connect from 2 devices to the server It doesn't work. I don't understand what I should do in this case. I mean, which thread should I connect to?

```
val client = HttpClient(Android) {
    install(Logging)
}

object KtorClient {
    var ipAddress: String = ""
    var ipv4Address = ""

    fun getData() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val data = client.request("http://$ipAddress:8080/api/data")
            println("DATA:${data.call.body<String>()}")
        }
    }

    fun otherGetData() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val data = client.request("https://$ipv4Address:8080/api/data")
            println("DATA:${data.call.body<String>()}")
        }
    }
} 
fun getLocalIpAddress(): String {
    try {
        val interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            val networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement()
            val addresses = networkInterface.inetAddresses
            while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                val address = addresses.nextElement()
                if (!address.isLoopbackAddress && address.hostAddress.contains(":").not()) {
                    return address.hostAddress ?: ""
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return "N/A"
}
```

Comment: server creation

Comment: private fun startServer() {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            embeddedServer(
                factory = Netty,
                port = 8080,
                module = Application::module,
            ).start(true)
        }
    }

Comment: The main thing that I do not understand is the server and the client through which IP methods are connected via wifi?

Comment: `this process should be through the local network, so the 1st device will have to open a hotspot` No. If you have already a local network then you do not need yet another hotspot. Both can then use the wifi of the local network. Please elaborate your setup

Comment: Yes, the 1st device opens the hotspot as a server, and the 2nd device must connect to it as a client @blackapps

Comment: I have to connect only 2 android devices locally to another local network

Comment: Sorry, i said that if you have already a local network you do not have to make a hotspot of one of your devices. Tell your setup. Tell about your local network.

Comment: I have only 2 android devices and I need to open a local network between them @blackapps

Comment: That is, there are only 2 devices, one is a server and the other is a client. @blackapps

Comment: When I send a request from the client to the server through the thread obtained using this function, a connection failure exception is issued

Comment: You cannot send a request before you established a connection. When exactly things go wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll fix it now :)

Comment: I connect 2 devices manually and then test

Comment: `And this process should be through the local network, ` Please change to `And this process should be without using a local network, `

Comment: Now I opened the hotspot from the 1st device and connected to it through the 2nd device. What should I do next? @blackapps

Comment: `And this process should be through the local network, ` Please change to `And this process should be without using a local network, `

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll fix it now :) @blackapps